# How to algebraically prove the sum of the projections of two sides of a triangle is equal to the projection of the third side of the triangle?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, triangles, alternative-proof, projection

[image]

Look at the picture above, graphically/geometrically, the green line is equal to the sum of the blue and red lines. But I am trying to think of an algebraical proof. Let's say the lengths of the side are $a$, $b$ and $c$, respectively, and the angles between the sides and the line onto which the sides are projected are $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$, respectively.

i.e. the question is: How to prove that $$a\cos{\alpha} + b\cos{\beta} = c\cos{\gamma}$$? I am always willing to be enlightened. Thank you very much.

Comment: One will certainly have to use the fact that the three angles of a triangle sum to $\pi$; that should produce an equation relating $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$.

Comment: Would using vectors, and the distributive property of dot products, be considered "algebraically" to you? In particular, have $\overrightarrow{A}$, $\overrightarrow{B}$ and $\overrightarrow{C}$ be the vectors of lengths $a$, $b$ and $c$, with $\overrightarrow{D} = (1,0)$ be the unit horizontal vector. We then get $\overrightarrow{A}+\overrightarrow{B}=\overrightarrow{C}$, so $\overrightarrow{D}\cdot(\overrightarrow{A}+\overrightarrow{B})=\overrightarrow{D}\cdot\overrightarrow{C}$, which leads to your $a\cos\alpha+b\cos\beta=c\cos\gamma$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Hi, this is actually where my question comes from. I was reading about dot product and realised that the distributive property of dot product requires my equation stated in the question to hold. However, I do not know how to algebraically prove it holds. So is there another way?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. As for another way to prove it, I haven't checked carefully but [Greg Martin's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4809103/how-to-algebraically-prove-the-sum-of-the-projections-of-two-sides-of-a-triangle#comment10230019_4809103) suggestion is how I would approach trying to do that.